# Image defined with og:image not showing on Pinterest

Tags: image, pinterest, facebook-opengraph

I am developing a website that has Pinterest share links on it. A link is something like:

```
http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://example.com/i293
```

The `og:image` meta tag defined in the header is:

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="photo.jpg"/>
```

Can anybody tell me why the image is not displayed when sharing on Pinterest?

`og:image` meta tag is working fine with Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Pinterest Developer Reference](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/rich-pins/reference/) it looks like [Open Graph](http://ogp.me)'s `og:image` tag is supported as an optional array for [Articles](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/rich-pins/articles/) and [Products](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/rich-pins/products/). It is not support for [Places](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/rich-pins/places/), [Movies](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/rich-pins/movies/), or [Recipes](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/rich-pins/recipes/).

Is it possible you are not setting your `og:type` to `article` or `product`? Also, if you don't set `og:type`, it will [default](http://ogp.me/#types) to `website`.